# How to create interactive command execution in Golang?

Tags: git, go, exec

I am trying to automate a git push from my Golang program. Is there any way I can pass username and password from the parent program into the exec-command?

```
func gitPush(gitExeLocation string, currentDir string) {

    fmt.Println("Pushing ...")
    args  := []string{"push", "-f", "origin", "HEAD"}

    cmd := exec.Command(gitExeLocation, args...)
    cmd.Dir = currentDir
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) 
    }
    defer stdin.Close()
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) 
        return
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    io.WriteString(stdin, "<Username>\n")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    io.WriteString(stdin, "<Password>\n")

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) 
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Succeeded.\n")

}
```

Comment: You would need to parse the output just like a user at the terminal. Why not provide the password without using the interactive prompt? (or even better, use the preferred and more secure method of an ssh key)

Comment: @JimB : I am not clear on how to provide the password by any other way. I would greatly appreciate if you could point me towards a better approach.

Comment: See the [git-credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) docs for git related functionality. The best solution is really to use a proper ssh public key (which should be encrypted and accessed via an ssh agent for even more security)

Comment: Another useful resource I've used to set up my ssh for git on several systems; https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it to work by setting the GIT_ASKPASS environment variable. However I would have liked a cleaner way of getting it done. Also I agree the SSH option is more secure, however having it as a requirement for users to use my application is kind of limiting.